# Why do my .net sitemap tabs move when I change the magnification of the IE10 browser?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using .NET Sitemap as tabs and they work great only problem is when the browser magnification is changed the tabs move to the right. I am using IE10 and at 100% magnification all is great but when I up it to 125% only the tabs move to the right... I have used a relative positioning and an absolute positioning and the same happens... Is this a MS IE10 thing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem!! Once I put a height and width on the DIV containing the sitemap the tabs stay fixed in position.
Thanks for all the brain power to help!!